# Azure App Service - An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-appservice

I am running an Azure App Service instance and after about a day or so with perhaps 15-30 people using the site, no one can access the MySQL database anymore and they just get this error when initiating a request:

"An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full"

I have many instances that work just fine with MSSQL (all of my other App Services have SSL's), but this is my first App Service that has given this error (and just so happens to be a MySQL database). This particular instance that has the issue also currently does not have an SSL, but I'm not sure if that has anything to do with the issue.

I have tried mimicking all settings from my working App Services and it still does not work. I'm not sure exactly how to diagnose the issue. All of my database calls are being closed and I am disposing of the connections, and also they all use the "using" statement, yet I still get this error. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
An operation on a socket could not be performed 
because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or 
because a queue was full
```

- The above error is usually not because of the MySQL but it is because of the OS on top the MySQL is running.
- There are two OS level reasons for this the first one is related to the memory allocation and the other one would regarding the TCP port allocation.
- The above error will be encountered is the MySQL program gets more memory (RAM) than OS itself so much so that the OS can't function properly, and you will get the error.
- The second reason would be that the port which is used is higher than the allowed TCP “ephemeral” ports. For windows the limit is set to 5000. Since you are using MYSQL and MYSQL default TCP port is `3306` . This probably is not the reason.
- Now to remedy the memory related issue we have to edit the `boot.ini` file in which we have to remove the `/3gb` switch as it will prevent the applications from accessing extra memory and will give more memory to the OS.
- To edit the `boot.ini` we can either do it through `Bootcfg` which is a command line tool for editing `boot.ini` another way to edit the boot.ini would be through a text editor ideally notepad. You can open the boot.ini by running the following command.

```
notepad.exe Boot.ini
```

Refer this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/editing-the-boot-ini-file) on editing `Boot.ini`

you can also refer this [Artilcle](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/understanding-the-error-8220-an-operation-on-a-socket-could-not/ba-p/383535) by Dan Benediktson on the same issue.